# Why does cumsum function not work in data.table package when attempting chaining?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I'm trying to add a `cumsum()` column to a dataframe using the data.table package per the below code and it doesn't work in this case (see section marked `# this doesn't work, after adding cumsum at the bottom:`). I've used `cumsum()` before but as standalone function in `setDT()`, but now I'm trying to chain it to the code and it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Here are the results I get for the code that does work (marked `# this works, before cumsum:` in the code below), except I added a column to the right "cumX" which is what I tried adding using chaining, whereby "cumX" runs a cumulative sum of column "1stStateX":

```
   Period 1stStateX   cumX
1:      1         0      0
2:      2         1      1
3:      3         1      2
4:      4         0      2
5:      5         0      2
```

In contrast, when I run the code marked `# this doesn't work...`, I get nothing back in the R studio console as illustrated here:

[image]

Also, when I run the code below marked `# this works, before cumsum:` for the simple `sum()` function (which works as intended), I noticed that the original dataframe `testDF` is altered as illustrated below. Why is that and how do I prevent that from happening?

[image]

Code:

```
library(data.table)

testDF <-
  data.frame(
    ID = c(rep(10,5),rep(50,5),rep(60,5)),
    Period = c(1:5,1:5,1:5),
    State = c("A","B","X","X","X",
              "A","A","A","A","A",
              "A","X","A","X","B")
  )

# this works, before cumsum:
setDT(testDF)[
  , `1stStateX` := .I == .I[State == 'X'][1],ID][
    , .(`1stStateX` = sum(`1stStateX`, na.rm = TRUE)), by = Period]


# this doesn't work, after adding cumsum at the bottom:
setDT(testDF)[
  , `1stStateX` := .I == .I[State == 'X'][1],ID][
    , .(`1stStateX` = sum(`1stStateX`, na.rm = TRUE)), by = Period][
      , cumX := cumsum(`1stStateX`),by = Period]
```

**Final solution using ismirsehregal´s answer, and after studying the recommended vignette I got chaining to work:**

```
library(data.table)

testDF <- data.frame(
  ID = c(rep(10,5),rep(50,5),rep(60,5)),
  Period = c(1:5,1:5,1:5),
  State = c("A","B","X","X","X",
            "A","A","A","A","A",
            "A","X","A","X","B")
)

testDT <- testDF
testDT <- setDT(testDT)[, `1stStateX` := .I == .I[State == 'X'][1],ID][
    , .(`1stStateX` = sum(`1stStateX`, na.rm = TRUE)), by = Period][
      , cumX := cumsum(`1stStateX`)]
testDT <- as.data.frame(testDT)
print(testDT)
```

Comment: "Why is that and how do I prevent that from happening?" You don't. That's the whole point of using `:=`. I strongly recommend reading the data.table vignettes. (You also need to explain what "this doesn't work" means exactly. An error? An unexpected result? ... And you need to explain what your code is supposed to do.)

Comment: It would be helfpul to see the expected output. Regarding your second question please see `?copy`.

Comment: Hi Roland, yes my OP fell short. I edited the post to show that I was trying to add a column for cumsum, using chaining. Also I edit for showing what I meant by "this doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your expected output, however, I guess your confusion is the result of chaining code that modifies an existing `data.table` object (Please see `` ?`:=` ``) and code which results in a new `data.table` object (Please see section `d) Select column(s) in j` [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)).

Please check the following:

```
library(data.table)

testDF <- data.frame(
    ID = c(rep(10,5),rep(50,5),rep(60,5)),
    Period = c(1:5,1:5,1:5),
    State = c("A","B","X","X","X",
              "A","A","A","A","A",
              "A","X","A","X","B")
  )

DT <- copy(testDF)
setDT(DT)

DT[, `1stStateX` := .I == .I[State == 'X'][1], ID] # this step changes DT by reference, please see ?`:=`
aggregatedDT <- DT[, .(`1stStateX` = sum(`1stStateX`, na.rm = TRUE)), by = Period] # this does not change DT and results in another data.table

aggregatedDT[, cumX := cumsum(`1stStateX`)]
print(aggregatedDT)
```

---

Result:

```
   Period 1stStateX cumX
1:      1         0    0
2:      2         1    1
3:      3         1    2
4:      4         0    2
5:      5         0    2
```

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to add an example of what I was trying to achieve with those code and example. I just edited the post to correct it.

Comment: @Village.Idyot please see my edit. You just need to drop the `by = Period`.

Comment: OK, and I went through the vignette and worked through every single example. Very helpful.